# Como ocultar variáveis undefined ou validadas apos recarregar a página?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tenho 2 variáveis que recebem os valores de um *input type month*, mas quando o código é executado pela primeira vez ou seja quando a página é carregada, as variáveis são *undefined* e o código pega a data do pc.

Gostaria de saber se é possível ocultá-las , ou fazer um *if* no *js* para que as variáveis só sejam validadas apos recarregar a página.

```html
 <body>

        <?php
//VARIAVEIS INDEFINIDAS
        $datee = explode('-', $_POST['datac']);
        $mes = $datee[1];
        $ano = $datee[0];
        $ultimo_dia = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, '01', $ano));
//----            

if ($mes == date('m')) {
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        } elseif ($mes == '') {
            $mes = date('m');
            $ano = date('o');
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        } else {
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        }
        
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="date.php">
            <input type="month" name="datac" value="<?php echo $ano ?>-<?php echo $mes ?>" required><input type="submit">
            <table class="table table-striped" width="210" border="2" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px"><center>Domingo</center></td>
                <td width="80px"><center>Segunda</center></td>
                <td width="80px"><center>Terça</center></td>
                <td width="80px"><center>Quarta</center></td>
                <td width="80px"><center>Quinta</center></td>
                <td width="80px"><center>Sexta</center></td>
                <td width="80px"><center>Sábado</center></td>
                </tr>
<?php
echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $dias; $i++) {
    $diadasemana = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $i, $ano));
    $cont = 0;
    if ($i == 1) {
        while ($cont < $diadasemana) {
            echo "<td></td>";
            $cont++;
        }
    }
    echo "<td width='100px' height='100px'><center>";
    echo $i;
    echo "</center></td>";
    if ($diadasemana == 6) {
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
?>
            </table>


        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já experimentas-te `<?php echo $ano ? $ano : "" ?>`

Comment: não, vou testar agora mesmo

Comment: você está falando para colocar isso na input?

Comment: acabei de tentar não deu resultado ;-;

Comment: Se calhar não percebi bem. Onde aparece `undefined`?  aparece "undefined" por texto no input?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: datac in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wallpaper\phpfiles\date.php on line XX

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wallpaper\phpfiles\date.php on line XX

Comment: São essas mensagens que aparecem

Comment: E erro de undefined não, se não for perdão ;-;

Comment: Seu $_POST['datac'] não está setado no começo pois não foi dado submit no form ainda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está dando `undefined` que ainda não tem o `$_POST`, então o que vc tem que fazer é verificar se tem o POST. No início do seu código coloque desta forma:

```
if(isset($_POST)){  
     $datee = explode('-', $_POST['datac']);
     $mes = $datee[1];
     $ano = $datee[0];
     $ultimo_dia = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, '01', $ano));
}else{
     $mes = '';
     $ano = '';
}
```

Se estiver vindo o POST vc vai setar as váriaveis `$mes` e `$ano` com os valores, senão , vai setar com ''.

Comment: erro continua persistindo

Comment: O erro acontece depois que vc da o submit ou já quando abre a página? Vc consegue identificar qual linha está dando o erro?

Comment: quando abro a página são essa linhas  $datee = explode('-', $_POST['datac']);,  $mes = $datee[1]; e $ultimo_dia = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, '01', $ano));

Comment: 3 erros : 
Notice: Undefined index: datac in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wallpaper\phpfiles\date.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wallpaper\phpfiles\date.php on line 20

Warning: mktime() expects parameter 6 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wallpaper\phpfiles\date.php on line 22

Comment: Mesmo com o isset($_POST) ele está entrando nessa parte do código? Troca por isset($_POST['datac']).

Comment: Valeu agora funcionou